# Always On HAG Primary Database Log Files

Tags: sql-server-2012, availability-groups

I tried to search the group but can't find similar answer,  I have a Primary Database that has a Large Transaction Log, I tried to shrink the file in the primary but can't set the default size to a smaller size, I believed I need to change the recovery model to simple to shrink the file, and now I'm not sure what will happen because the database is part of HAG/Always on and it is the primary node. I tried the `readable secondary set = no`, nothing changes, I can't managed to resize the default initial size to a lower size.

Comment: HAG? Not heard that before.

Comment: High Availability Group = HAG

Comment: That's not a thing. They are Availability Groups.

Answer (score 2):

Can you quantify 'large'?  Are things breaking?  What's the reason you want to shrink it?

Regardless, you won't be able to switch the DB to SIMPLE mode if it's in an AG.  You'll get the following:

> Msg 1468, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 The operation cannot be performed
>   on database "MyDBName" because it is involved in a database mirroring
>   session or an availability group. Some operations are not allowed on a
>   database that is participating in a database mirroring session or in
>   an availability group.
>
> Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 ALTER
>   DATABASE statement failed.

What I would do is go find out if transaction log backups are being taken and their frequency.  in FULL recovery model, the log file isn't automatically truncated and cleared, you'll need to take log backups for that to happen. (In SIMPLE recovery, the log is automatically cleared so there's no need to maintain it.

If you're taking log backups, you may need to take them more frequently as the log file could be filling up between log backups.

https://www.sqlshack.com/beginners-guide-sql-server-transaction-logs/
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345583(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have figures it out, i need to do two log backup to shrink the log files, i don't know if that is a bug, but when i tried for the first time it did not shrink, then i tried again to have the log backup and it worked.